# JQuery matchMedia .scroll not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the logo on my website to fade when I scroll but only when it is at the media query for mid-width: 992px. This code works on load, but not on resize of the window and I can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});

//Large Screen Check Scroll Event
var screenSize = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)");
scrollFade(screenSize);
scrollFade.addListener(screenSize);

function scrollFade(screenSize){
   if (screenSize.matches){ // if media query matches
     $(window).scroll(function(){
       $(".logo").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 600);
     });//do the thing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `addListener()` is backwards. Instead, the function should be attached to the matchMedia variable like:

`screenSize.addListener(scrollFade);`

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9t5hvc78/2/)

You also may want to stop the scroll event if the user changes window size so it no longer matches when it previously did. To do so, you can add an `else` statement and add:

`$(window).off('scroll');`

[JS Fiddle - off()](https://jsfiddle.net/9t5hvc78/3/)

Comment: Thanks! I had tried switching the event listener thinking that was the problem earlier and never switched it back. The else statement was definitely what I was missing.